# Getting 404 error when callback after authentication(Spring Boot + Angular + Okta)

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, okta

Hi I am now using Angular + Spring Boot to build a website, in my website, I am using Okta Single-Page App to do authentication. For the frontend, I am using okta-angular, and follow the instructions here: https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/okta-angular. I am using implicit flow. In order to keep simple, I used okta hosted sign-in widget.

My frontend code like this:

app.module.ts

```
import {
  OKTA_CONFIG,
  OktaAuthModule
} from '@okta/okta-angular';

const oktaConfig = {
  issuer: 'https://{yourOktaDomain}.com/oauth2/default',
  clientId: '{clientId}',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:{port}/implicit/callback',
  pkce: true
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    OktaAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: OKTA_CONFIG, useValue: oktaConfig }
  ],
})
export class MyAppModule { }
```

then I use OktaAuthGuard in app-routing.module.ts

```
import {
  OktaAuthGuard,
  ...
} from '@okta/okta-angular';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'protected',
    component: MyProtectedComponent,
    canActivate: [ OktaAuthGuard ],
  },
  ...
]
```

Also in the app-routing.module.ts I am using OktaCallBackComponent.

of course I have login/logout button at headers:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {OktaAuthService} from '@okta/okta-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './app-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-header.component.scss']
})
export class AppHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  constructor(public oktaAuth: OktaAuthService) {
    // Subscribe to authentication state changes
    this.oktaAuth.$authenticationState.subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated: boolean) => this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
    );
  }
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
  }

  login() {
    this.oktaAuth.loginRedirect('/');
  }

  logout() {
    this.oktaAuth.logout('/');
  }

}
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="!isAuthenticated" (click)="login()"> Login </a>
        <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="isAuthenticated" (click)="logout()"> Logout </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

After user login at frontend, I will pass Authoirization header to backend, and 
At the backend, I use spring security to protect backend api.
like this:

```
import com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OktaOAuth2WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Disable CSRF (cross site request forgery)
        http.csrf().disable();

        // No session will be created or used by spring security
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken();

        Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if i run angular and spring boot separately in terminals. I can log in, and I can get user info at backend.

But the problem is when we were using gradle build and to deploy, we will put angular compiled code to static folder under spring boot project. At this time if I run the project:

```
java -jar XX.jar
```

And I open at localhost:8080.

**I login, then at this time, the authentication callback will throw 404 not found error.**

**In my understanding, the reason is that when I run jar file, and I didn't define controller for the "callback" url. But if I run angular and spring boot separately, angular is hosted by nodejs, and I used okta callbackcomponent, so everything works.**

**So what should I do to fix the problem? I mean, what should I do to let it work as a jar file? should I define a callback controller? but what should I do in callback controller? will it conflict with frontend code??**

Comment: I am thinking if I need to put angular into jar file, will it be a must to put login logout to backend rather than frontend? Like using this sample: https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/blob/master/okta-hosted-login/src/main/java/com/okta/spring/example/CodeFlowExampleApplication.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck! I just published a [blog post](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/06/17/angular-docker-spring-boot) today that shows how to take an Angular + Spring Boot app that runs separately (with Okta's SDKs) and package them in a single JAR. You can still develop each app independently using `ng serve` and `./gradlew bootRun`, but you can also run them in a single instance using `./gradlew bootRun -Pprod`. The disadvantage to running in prod mode is you won't get hot-reload in Angular. Here are [the steps I used](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/06/17/angular-docker-spring-boot#combine-your-angular-spring-boot-app-into-a-single-jar) in the aforementioned tutorial.

Create a new AuthService service that will communicate with your Spring Boot API for authentication logic.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { User } from './user';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json');

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  $authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private location: Location) {
  }

  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user`, {headers}).pipe(
      map((response: User) => {
        if (response !== null) {
          this.$authenticationState.next(true);
          return response;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.getUser().toPromise().then((user: User) => { 
      return user !== undefined;
    }).catch(() => {
      return false;
    })
  }

  login(): void { 
    location.href =
      `${location.origin}${this.location.prepareExternalUrl('oauth2/authorization/okta')}`;
  }

  logout(): void { 
    const redirectUri = `${location.origin}${this.location.prepareExternalUrl('/')}`;

    this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/logout`, {}).subscribe((response: any) => {
      location.href = response.logoutUrl + '?id_token_hint=' + response.idToken
        + '&post_logout_redirect_uri=' + redirectUri;
    });
  }
}
```

Create a `user.ts` file in the same directory, to hold your `User` model.

```
export class User {
  sub: number;
  fullName: string;
}
```

Update `app.component.ts` to use your new `AuthService` in favor of `OktaAuthService`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Notes';
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  isCollapsed = true;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = await this.auth.isAuthenticated();
    this.auth.$authenticationState.subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated: boolean)  => this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
    );
  }
}
```

Change the buttons in `app.component.html` to reference the `auth` service instead of `oktaAuth`.

```html
<button *ngIf="!isAuthenticated" (click)="auth.login()"
        class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="login">Login</button>
<button *ngIf="isAuthenticated" (click)="auth.logout()"
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="logout">Logout</button>
```

Update `home.component.ts` to use `AuthService` too.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = await this.auth.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

If you used OktaDev Schematics to integrate Okta into your Angular app, delete `src/app/auth-routing.module.ts` and `src/app/shared/okta`.

Modify `app.module.ts` to remove the `AuthRoutingModule` import, add `HomeComponent` as a declaration, and import `HttpClientModule`.

Add the route for `HomeComponent` to `app-routing.module.ts`.

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

Create a `proxy.conf.js` file to proxy certain requests to your Spring Boot API on `http://localhost:8080`.

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ['/user', '/api', '/oauth2', '/login'],
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    secure: false,
    logLevel: "debug"
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Add this file as a `proxyConfig` option in `angular.json`.

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "notes:build",
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
  },
  ...
},
```

Remove Okta’s Angular SDK and OktaDev Schematics from your Angular project.

```sh
npm uninstall @okta/okta-angular @oktadev/schematics
```

At this point, your Angular app won't contain any Okta-specific code for authentication. Instead, it relies on your Spring Boot app to provide that.

To configure your Spring Boot app to include Angular, you need to configure Gradle (or Maven) to build your Spring Boot app when you pass in `-Pprod`, you'll need to adjust routes to be SPA-aware, and modify Spring Security to allow access to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

In my example, I used Gradle and Kotlin.

First, create a `RouteController.kt` that routes all requests to `index.html`.

```kotlin
package com.okta.developer.notes

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

@Controller
class RouteController {

    @RequestMapping(value = ["/{path:[^\\.]*}"])
    fun redirect(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
        return "forward:/"
    }
}
```

Modify `SecurityConfiguration.kt` to allow anonymous access to static web files, the `/user` info endpoint, and to add additional security headers.

```kotlin
package com.okta.developer.notes

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher

@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        //@formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/*.{js,html,css}").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/user").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()

        http.requiresChannel()
                .requestMatchers(RequestMatcher {
                    r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null
                }).requiresSecure()

        http.csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())

        http.headers()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'; report-to /csp-report-endpoint/")
                .and()
                .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN)
                .and()
                .featurePolicy("accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; microphone 'none'")

        //@formatter:on
    }
}
```

Create a `UserController.kt` that can be used to determine if the user is logged in.

```kotlin
package com.okta.developer.notes

import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class UserController() {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    fun user(@AuthenticationPrincipal user: OidcUser?): OidcUser? {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Previously, Angular handled logout. Add a `LogoutController` that will handle expiring the session as well as sending information back to Angular so it can logout from Okta.

```kotlin
package com.okta.developer.notes

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcIdToken
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

@RestController
class LogoutController(val clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository) {

    val registration: ClientRegistration = clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId("okta");

    @PostMapping("/api/logout")
    fun logout(request: HttpServletRequest,
               @AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "idToken") idToken: OidcIdToken): ResponseEntity<*> {
        val logoutUrl = this.registration.providerDetails.configurationMetadata["end_session_endpoint"]
        val logoutDetails: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        logoutDetails["logoutUrl"] = logoutUrl.toString()
        logoutDetails["idToken"] = idToken.tokenValue
        request.session.invalidate()
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body<Map<String, String>>(logoutDetails)
    }
}
```

Finally, I configured Gradle to build a JAR with Angular included.

Start by importing `NpmTask` and adding the Node Gradle plugin in `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
import com.moowork.gradle.node.npm.NpmTask

plugins {
    ...
    id("com.github.node-gradle.node") version "2.2.4"
    ...
}
```

Then, define the location of your Angular app and configuration for the Node plugin.

```kotlin
val spa = "${projectDir}/../notes";

node {
    version = "12.16.2"
    nodeModulesDir = file(spa)
}
```

Add a `buildWeb` task:

```kotlin
val buildWeb = tasks.register<NpmTask>("buildNpm") {
    dependsOn(tasks.npmInstall)
    setNpmCommand("run", "build")
    setArgs(listOf("--", "--prod"))
    inputs.dir("${spa}/src")
    inputs.dir(fileTree("${spa}/node_modules").exclude("${spa}/.cache"))
    outputs.dir("${spa}/dist")
}
```

And modify the `processResources` task to build Angular when `-Pprod` is passed in.

```kotlin
tasks.processResources {
    rename("application-${profile}.properties", "application.properties")
    if (profile == "prod") {
        dependsOn(buildWeb)
        from("${spa}/dist/notes") {
            into("static")
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to combine both apps using `./gradlew bootJar -Pprod` or see them running using `./gradlew bootRun -Pprod`.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple solution, I added a config file in spring boot to reroute implicit/callback to angular "index.html":

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class ReroutingConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/implicit/**", "/home")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                    @Override
                    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                        Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);

                        return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                                : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

It works but I am not sure if this is a good practise.

Comment: You can certainly do it this way, but it's less secure than my version. This is because it's storing the access token on the client instead of on the server. It's much harder to steal access tokens from a session on the server than it is from a browser. However, it's probably something you don't need to worry about as long as no one from marketing adds trackers and 3rd party scripts that might be compromised. I'd make sure you have a solid CSP.

Comment: @MattRaible one thing is if we want to do authentication on spring boot side, a easier way will be "Web" Okta application, right?